# Copy multiple files to a folder in newbie appelscript

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to make an Applescript that takes a list of names and makes a set of folders from it. And then copies files from a choosen folder into each of these newly created folders.

I have search for the answer, but didn't understand them. So if you could be so kind to explaine what and why I should change the code, it would be a great learning experience for me.

```
set destinationFolder to choose folder
set {text returned:textReturned} to display dialog "enter folder names" default answer           return & return & return
if textReturned is "" then return
set folderWithFiles to (choose folder with prompt "Where are the files at?")
repeat with aLine in (get paragraphs of textReturned)
if contents of aLine is not "" then
    do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of (POSIX path of dest  inationFolder & aLine)
    set folderNew to aLine & ":" as alias
    set dest to folderNew on destinationFolder -- as alias
    tell application "Finder"
        duplicate every file of folderWithFiles to dest
    end tell
end if
end repeat
```

Thanks in advance
Updated: posted answer to myself

Comment: That was the plan all along. When I found the answer I had to wait 5 hours before being able to post an answer. And another 48 to be acept it. So patience boys.

Comment: So I ended up learning something from this question after all ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got help from StefanK at macscripter.net

Here is the complete code:

```
set destinationFolder to choose folder
set {text returned:textReturned} to display dialog "enter folder names" default answer    return & return & return
if textReturned is "" then return
try
    set theFiles to (choose file with prompt "Where are the files at?" with multiple   selections allowed)
end try
repeat with aLine in (get paragraphs of textReturned)
   if contents of aLine is not "" then
       set newFolder to (destinationFolder as text) & aLine
       do shell script "/bin/mkdir -p " & quoted form of POSIX path of newFolder
       try
           tell application "Finder" to duplicate theFiles to folder newFolder
       end try
end if
end repeat
```